# Values storing 2 times in database

Tags: ios, database, insert, sqlite, uigesturerecognizer

I have to insert x & y touch coordinates values in database. But it storing 2 times in database. When i long press i'm getting touch coordinates and insert some tag for button_tag. But i longpress once, why the values are storing 2 times

Table:

```
button_tag   xcoor    ycoor
2             123.5    320.9
23            123.5    320.9


- (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].x, [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].y);


     xcor = [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].x;
     ycor = [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].y;


    universal_button_tag = arc4random() % 99;

    NSLog(@"Universal Button tag: %d",universal_button_tag);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT button_tag,xcoor,ycoor FROM touch where  button_tag='%d' AND xcoor = '%f' AND ycoor = '%f'",universal_button_tag,xcor,ycor] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        BOOL favExist = false;

        sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                favExist = true;
            }
        }


        if(!favExist){


            //Changes



            const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into touch (button_tag,xcoor,ycoor) values ('%d','%f','%f')", universal_button_tag,xcor,ycor] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            //----

            NSLog(@"sql insert is %s",sqlInsert);


            // [catID release];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            NSLog(@"error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: your detection of `favExist` looks false to me. You try to find an existing record in your database given a random id. The record will never exist, or it is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gesture recognizer's target action is called for different states of the gesture recognizer. You need to check the state in your method.

```
- (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // handle completed gesture
    }
}
```

See the docs for `UIGestureRecognizer` for more details.

Comment: before my code was working. I removed one column from database. After it is not working

Comment: What does that have to do with your original question or my answer?